# Not receiving WM_DISPLAYCHANGE

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I've created a simple window to receive messages:

```
CreateWindow(L"MyClass", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, 0, 0, 0);
```

I'm intrested in [`WM_DISPLAYCHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to detect when monitors are plugged in/removed, but I never receive the message.  My window receives other messages, but never `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE`.  Why?

Comment: "This message is only sent to top-level windows. For all other windows it is posted.", is that correct for you?

Comment: You've also declared it as a message-only window - I wonder if that causes it to be missed (as by definition it won't ever display anything therefore care about the resolution)? - just a guess.

Comment: @DavidKernin: Given that `hwndParent` is `0`, isn't my window considered top-level?  And honestly, I'm not sure what the exact difference between "sent" and "posted" would be in this situation.

Comment: @josh3736, which messages do you actually receive on that window? And publish the part where you pump the messages for the window(s).

Comment: @josh3736: "sent" means a message is delivered directly to a window's wndproc without being queued. "posted" means a message is put in the message queue of a window's owning thread and then is dispatched to the window's wndproc when the message queue is processed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might have something to do with it:

[Message-only windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#message_only)

> A *message-only* window enables you to send and receive messages. It is not visible, has no z-order, cannot be enumerated, **and does not receive broadcast messages**. The window simply dispatches messages.

Comment: You can create a top level window that never gets shown rather than a message only window to get broadcast messages, e.g. CreateWindowEx(0, szClassName, 0, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, hThisInstance, NULL);

Comment: I think you can have a message window by instantiating/deriving directly from CCmdTarget (instead of CWnd).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should satisfy following two conditions if you want receive WM_DISPLAYCHANGE msg from Windows：

1. Top-level Window, you shoule create a window that hwndParent parameter is NULL or HWND_DESKTOP
2. Message Loop, just like this:

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

I have tested that disable message loop, e.g. use `while(1) {}` before message loop, in this condition i can't receive WM_DISPLAYCHANGE when resolution changed.